# helm hook post-install shell script execution

Tags: sh, hook, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set helm "post-install" hook and seeing below error.
ERROR:
**sh: script/jenkins.sh: not found**

postinstall.yaml content

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: post-install-jenkins-job
        image: alpine:3.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "scripts/jenkins.sh"]
      restartPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```

Folder structure of helm package
scripts/jenkins.h is the script that I am trying to execute with "postinstall.yaml" as post-install helm hook.

```
riq-agent
├── Chart.yaml
├── README.md
├── scripts
│   └── jenkins.sh
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── Untitled-1.yml
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── awssecret.yaml
│   ├── clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── configurationFiles-configmap.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── hook-aws-ecr.yaml
│   ├── initializationFiles-configmap.yaml
│   ├── postinstall.yaml
│   ├── pvc.yaml
│   ├── secrets.yaml
│   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   ├── servicemonitor.yaml
│   ├── svc.yaml
│   └── tests
│       ├── test-configmap.yaml
│       └── test.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Is there any mistakes in the way that I am trying to execute a shell script (stored within helm package) in helm hook?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be executed, `scripts/jenkins.sh` should be a part of `post-install-jenkins-job` container, mounted as a volume. You can [populate a volume with data stored in a configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap).

**postinstall-configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-postinstall-configmap
data:
  jenkins.sh: |-
{{ .Files.Get "scripts/jenkins.sh" | indent 4}}
```

**postinstall.yaml**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: post-install-jenkins-job
        image: alpine:3.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/scripts/jenkins.sh"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /opt/scripts
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}-postinstall-configmap
            defaultMode: 0777
      restartPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```